# SQL Created XML File - Setting Checkbox Status

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, checkbox, dapper

I'm using SQL to generate an XML file as a word document (DocumentAssembler) which, amongst other things, needs to change the value of a checkbox.  I have 2 checkboxes on my document and need to check "yes" (FIRBY) or "no" (FIRBN) as applicable.  I'm struggling with the syntax.

I have created the control in my word document and have tried both boolean and true/false as result but keep getting this error:

> *Schema Validation Error: The 'Control' attribute is not declared*

```
(Select 
   (Case when GroupID = 2 and QuestionID = 3 then
        #checked status is true#
   else 
        #checked status is false#
   end) as FIRBN,

   (Case when GroupID = 2 and QuestionID = 3  then 
        #checked status is false#
   else 
        #checked status is true# 
   end) as FIRBY
   from  [dbo].[fQuestionGroupForSale] (@DevelopmentID, @LotNr, @SaleSeqNr, 2)
FOR XML PATH ('FIRB'),TYPE)
```

Things I have tried:

Unicode in SQL:

```
nchar(unicode(2610)) else nchar(unicode(2611))
```

XML Code by creating blank document with a checkbox looks like:

```
<w:alias w:val="FIRBY"/><w:tag w:val="FIRBY"/>
<w:id w:val="299657556"/>
<w15:appearance w15:val="tags"/>
<w14:checkbox><w14:checked w14:val="1"/>
<w14:checkedState w14:val="2612" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
<w14:uncheckedState w14:val="2610" w14:font="MS Gothic"/></w14:checkbox>
```

and using wingdings it looks like:

```
-<w:r>
<w:sym w:char="F052" w:font="Wingdings 2"/>
</w:r>
-<w:r>
<w:sym w:char="F0A3" w:font="Wingdings 2"/>
</w:r>
```

TIA

Comment: Try to create the XML manually and find out, how this should look like. Then - if you need help for this - add this working XML to your question and we will help you to build it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Shnugo.  Have edited to add things I have tried.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed:

NCHAR(0x2610)

NCHAR(0x2611)